# Web Worker is not connecting with the website

Tags: javascript

*note console.log also doesnt work

File directory

```
Worker
> worker.min.js
> web-worker.js

index.html
```

The above is my file directory. The `index.html` file is connected to the `Worker/worker.min.js` file.

```
// worker.min.js file
const w = new Worker("Worker/web-worker.js"); //Throws error when put only `web-worker.js`
w.postMessage("...msg");
w.onmessage = () => {
  alert("Worker responded");
}
```

```
// web-worker.js file
onmessage = () => {
  alert("Worker recieved the message");
  postMessage("..msg");
}
```

But, the alert message is not shown. Can anyone tell me how to fix this.

I will be really greatful if someone helped.
Browser: Latest version of Chrome™

Comment: `alert` is not supported in workers - use `console.log`